# How to fix regex to only select from campaign to base_bid - and not skip over my ending string - base_bid text

Tags: javascript, regex

My regex is grabbing this:

```
campaign":{"id":100134,"state":"active","code":null,"advertiser_id":21147,"line_item_id":44854,"creative_id":481909,"pixel_id":null,"short_name":null,"name":"WSPA ROE 0711","profile_id":438747,"start_date":"2011-07-06 00:00:00","end_date":null,"timezone":"Europe/London","priority":5,"cadence_modifier_enabled":true,"cpc_goal":null,"cpm_bid_type":"base","base_bid":0.16,"min_bid":null,"max_bid":null,"bid_margin":0,"roadblock_creatives":false,"roadblock_type":"no_roadblock","inventory_type":"real_time","last_modified":"2014-05-28 16:06:01","max_learn_bid":null,"cadence_type":"creative","click_url":null,"require_cookie_for_tracking":true}}}{"response":{"status":"OK","count":1,"start_element":0,"num_elements":100,"campaign":{"id":12039447,"state":"active","code":null,"advertiser_id":180353,"line_item_id":2703939,"creative_id":null,"pixel_id":null,"short_name":null,"name":"Copy Jan Programmatic BAU - 6 RTG - Register 2a. (7D)","profile_id":51061721,"start_date":"2015-08-20 00:00:00","end_date":null,"timezone":"Europe/London","priority":5,"cadence_modifier_enabled":false,"cpc_goal":null,"cpm_bid_type":"base","base_bid":1.25,|100134
```

When I want it to grab:

```
campaign":{"id":100134,"state":"active","code":null,"advertiser_id":21147,"line_item_id":44854,"creative_id":481909,"pixel_id":null,"short_name":null,"name":"WSPA ROE 0711","profile_id":438747,"start_date":"2011-07-06 00:00:00","end_date":null,"timezone":"Europe/London","priority":5,"cadence_modifier_enabled":true,"cpc_goal":null,"cpm_bid_type":"base","base_bid":0.16,
```

and

```
campaign":{"id":12039447,"state":"active","code":null,"advertiser_id":180353,"line_item_id":2703939,"creative_id":null,"pixel_id":null,"short_name":null,"name":"Copy Jan Programmatic BAU - 6 RTG - Register 2a. (7D)","profile_id":51061721,"start_date":"2015-08-20 00:00:00","end_date":null,"timezone":"Europe/London","priority":5,"cadence_modifier_enabled":false,"cpc_goal":null,"cpm_bid_type":"base","base_bid":1.25,
```

ie two lots.  And so print:

```
100134|0.16
12039447|1.25
```

How can I fix this?

Here is my text javascript

```
</head>
<body>

<script>
  var theString = '{"response":{"status":"OK","count":1,"start_element":0,"num_elements":100,"campaign":{"id":100134,"state":"active","code":null,"advertiser_id":21147,"line_item_id":44854,"creative_id":481909,"pixel_id":null,"short_name":null,"name":"WSPA ROE 0711","profile_id":438747,"start_date":"2011-07-06 00:00:00","end_date":null,"timezone":"Europe/London","priority":5,"cadence_modifier_enabled":true,"cpc_goal":null,"cpm_bid_type":"base","base_bid":0.16,"min_bid":null,"max_bid":null,"bid_margin":0,"roadblock_creatives":false,"roadblock_type":"no_roadblock","inventory_type":"real_time","last_modified":"2014-05-28 16:06:01","max_learn_bid":null,"cadence_type":"creative","click_url":null,"require_cookie_for_tracking":true}}}{"response":{"status":"OK","count":1,"start_element":0,"num_elements":100,"campaign":{"id":12039447,"state":"active","code":null,"advertiser_id":180353,"line_item_id":2703939,"creative_id":null,"pixel_id":null,"short_name":null,"name":"Copy Jan Programmatic BAU - 6 RTG - Register 2a. (7D)","profile_id":51061721,"start_date":"2015-08-20 00:00:00","end_date":null,"timezone":"Europe/London","priority":5,"cadence_modifier_enabled":false,"cpc_goal":null,"cpm_bid_type":"base","base_bid":1.25,"min_bid":null,"max_bid":null,"bid_margin":0,"roadblock_creatives":false,"roadblock_type":"no_roadblock","inventory_type":"real_time","last_modified":"2016-02-09 12:11:02","max_learn_bid":null,"cadence_type":"advertiser","click_url":null,"require_cookie_for_tracking":true}}}';

var regexp = /campaign":{"id":([0-9]+),"state":.*"base_bid":([0-9.]+),/g;

var match = regexp.exec(theString);
while (match != null){
    console.log(match[0] + '|' + match[1]);
    var match = regexp.exec(theString);
}

</script>
</body>
<html>
```

Answer (score 0):

I think the problem with that regular expression is that the `.*` before "base_bid" is matching everything between the first "id" and the final "base_bid". I'm not sure how to fix the regular expression.

However, have you ever used `JSON.parse`? It is built in to Javascript and will convert a valid JSON string into a javascript object. If you were able to split your `jsonString` into individual responses, you could get to the campaign ID and base bid values pretty simply.

This isn't a perfect solution, but I'll try illustrate my idea here:

```
// Your original string.
var jsonString = '{"response":{"status":"OK","count":1,"start_element":0,"num_elements":100,"campaign":{"id":100134,"state":"active","code":null,"advertiser_id":21147,"line_item_id":44854,"creative_id":481909,"pixel_id":null,"short_name":null,"name":"WSPA ROE 0711","profile_id":438747,"start_date":"2011-07-06 00:00:00","end_date":null,"timezone":"Europe/London","priority":5,"cadence_modifier_enabled":true,"cpc_goal":null,"cpm_bid_type":"base","base_bid":0.16,"min_bid":null,"max_bid":null,"bid_margin":0,"roadblock_creatives":false,"roadblock_type":"no_roadblock","inventory_type":"real_time","last_modified":"2014-05-28 16:06:01","max_learn_bid":null,"cadence_type":"creative","click_url":null,"require_cookie_for_tracking":true}}}{"response":{"status":"OK","count":1,"start_element":0,"num_elements":100,"campaign":{"id":12039447,"state":"active","code":null,"advertiser_id":180353,"line_item_id":2703939,"creative_id":null,"pixel_id":null,"short_name":null,"name":"Copy Jan Programmatic BAU - 6 RTG - Register 2a. (7D)","profile_id":51061721,"start_date":"2015-08-20 00:00:00","end_date":null,"timezone":"Europe/London","priority":5,"cadence_modifier_enabled":false,"cpc_goal":null,"cpm_bid_type":"base","base_bid":1.25,"min_bid":null,"max_bid":null,"bid_margin":0,"roadblock_creatives":false,"roadblock_type":"no_roadblock","inventory_type":"real_time","last_modified":"2016-02-09 12:11:02","max_learn_bid":null,"cadence_type":"advertiser","click_url":null,"require_cookie_for_tracking":true}}}';

// Find where the first response ends and the second begins.
// (+ 1 because we need to get between the }{ when we split.)
// (It would be great if the strings weren't concatenated to begin with.)
var splitIndex = jsonString.indexOf('}{') + 1;
// Get the two individual JSON responses.
var firstResponseJson = jsonString.substring(0, splitIndex);
var secondResponseJson = jsonString.substring(splitIndex);

// Parse the first JSON string.
var firstResponse = JSON.parse(firstResponseJson);
// We now have an Object with a "response" attribute, which contains
// all the information we need about this campaign.
var firstId = firstResponse.response.campaign.id;
var firstBaseBid = firstResponse.response.campaign.base_bid;
console.log(firstId + '|' + firstBaseBid);
```

Sorry for not having an answer using regexes, but I think it will ultimately be a more flexible solution if you are able to parse that JSON into an object.